# Symfony2 - Cast a String to Int in twig

Tags: symfony, casting, twig, render

I would like to know if it was possible to cast a String to an Int in twig. I try to see if a user has enough credit or not to buy a cours. For that, I calculate the amount of credit with a render in the template (because I need the value in the template, and I didn't found a better way to do it...) like this :

```
{% set creditUser %}
    {{render(controller('L3L2EntraideBundle:Credits:sommeCredits'))}}
{% endset %}
```

But when I try to compare creditUser :

```
{% if creditUser < c.idCompetenceCours.prix %}disabled="false"{% endif %}
```

Symfony return me a beautiful error : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Object of class Twig_Markup could not be converted to int") in L3L2UserBundle:Profile:modal_prendre_rdv.html.twig at line 21.

Any idea ? Thank you in advance for my first question on Stackoverflow and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not string but Twig_Markup

```
{% if creditUser.__toString < c.idCompetenceCours.prix %}
```

but this is not good approach you should get this value from object/variable not from rendered template

Comment: Thank you for your response but I need a integer to compare with the int 'c.idCompetenceCours.prix' (sorry if it wasn't clear).

Comment: creditUser.__toString will 'cast' Twig_Markup as string and it will compare as int
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php table "Comparison with Various Types"

Comment: Hi, I'm Steve, and I'm from three years in the future! Anyway, this allowed me to perform some math on the value of a dropdown I have, so thanks! But where is `__toString` from? I have never come across it in the Twig docs.

Comment: In the question there was an attempt to compare what was rendered in a condition.  Render returns the php object Twig_Markup what has implementation of the magic method `__toString`. You should never call like this. You should instead pass the value from controller or use a service as a global twig method.